# Where to sell items when starting out in Pool of Radiance?

Tags: pool-of-radiance

I found an armor vendor in Phlan, but he only seems interested in selling items to my party; is it possible to sell items in Phlan? If so, roughly where on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual, you can sell items in a shop by highlighting the item you want to sell with the cursor, and the merchant will make you an offer.

The shops in Phlan are located together in the south-east part of the city, just west of the tavern. There are several.